# ¿Cómo poner una imagen de fondo que abarque toda la pantalla?

Tags: css, angular-cli

Hola camaradas fijense que estoy trabajando en un componente html en angular que se llama homepage quiero que en esa pagina se muestre un fondo con una imagen pero me aparece en otro lado y no abarca toda la pantalla.

Este es el código que tengo para la imagen:

```html
<div class="container text-center pb-5">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c5/d5/a1/c5d5a15f42ba0abcfb1d6b15181e20c0.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; z-index: -100; opacity: 0.75;">

</div>
```

Así es como me aparece:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agredecería mucho si me ayudan.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograr el efecto deseado con el siguiente código css, sin embargo te recomiendo usar media queries con el fin de usar imágenes que cuenten con diferentes resoluciones dependiendo la pantalla:

```css
div {
  background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c5/d5/a1/c5d5a15f42ba0abcfb1d6b15181e20c0.jpg) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa este CSS para el fondo:

```
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

también podrías usar la siguiente forma para trabajar con la etiqueta img:

```
img {
width:100%;
height:100%;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

Saludos